# Way of plotting data into boxes instead of pyramids using mplot3d

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So I have an array of values that I am trying to plot using the `plot_surface` command. Specifically I have a 30x30 array with one in the middle and zeros elsewhere. When I plot it this is what I obtain: [image: pyramid]

I would like however for the value to be represented as a cuboid. Is that possible?

Thank you

**edit**: Code that shows the figure

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

N=30
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = y = np.arange(0, N)
z = np.zeros((N,N))
z[15,15] = 1
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, z, cmap='YlOrBr')
plt.show(block=False)
```

Comment: Post some minimal code so people can more easily help you.

Comment: How can one value be diplayed as a 3D cuboid? I guess, you have to explain your expected output better. Any sample figure, you have seen somewhere else?

Comment: One value can be displayed as a cuboid by making the height of the cuboid proportional to the value that has to be plotted (in this case 1). So what I want is essentially a 3d histogram out of the initial array (z).

Comment: [`ax.bar3d`](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.bar3d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a 3D bar plot will give what you're looking for.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

N=30
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = y = np.arange(0, N)
z_bottom = np.zeros((N,N))
z_top = z_bottom.copy()
z_top[15,15] = 1
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
ax.bar3d(X.ravel(), Y.ravel(), z_bottom.ravel(), 1, 1, z_top.ravel())
plt.show(block=False)
```

[image]

The [full documentation is here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D) if you want to play with the colors and so forth.